# How to read a sound file and send it as a http request in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, http-post, python-requests

I am reading the folder, which as sound file from the C:\Users\Desktop\Audio\ and later trying to send this as a http request to the server. But I am not able to send the http request to the server. Can some tell me what is the mistake that I am making here. I made some mistake within that ** ---- **.  I am also getting the error as : Traceback (most recent call last):

I am getting the error as :

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="QueryRetry"

Content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8

-Context: 03df2e8d-6d9b-4148-a7a5-9f857f9879c1

{"Cause":1,"Name":"AUDIO_INFO","Prompt":"Sorry, speech not recognized. Please try again."}

Comment: Fix this error: "Permission denied", then update your question.

Comment: I did as you said. now I am getting the error as above.

Comment: It looks like "boundary" is not in that scope. So make "boundary" from myplayfunction() available at "headers" definition.

Comment: I updated my code. Can you please tell me how to send the read data via http request. I can see in the ouput that I can read or parse the sound file.

Comment: They don't recognize what you send them. Make sure that what you send is what they expect.